Life Cycle Assessment in Regulation
The California Air Resources Board established and maintains a Low Carbon Fuel Standard for automotive fuels sold in that state.
A controversial aspect of that regulation involved the use of Life Cycle Assessment (LCA) as the primary means of determining a fuel's eligibility under the standard.
Life Cycle Assessment is a method for measuring the environmental harm attributable to a product or practice as a function of all aspects of that product/practice's provision and utilization from the acquisition of raw material to the disposal of the final product.  It facilitates the comparison of, for example, fully electric vehicles (EV) to those using internal combustion engines (ICE) on an apples-to-apples basis, the ICE car's manufacturing is far less polluting, as is its disposal, compared to the EV - but the EV produces far less pollution during the use phase, and because of the long operational life of both this becomes the dominant factor in favor of EVs.
The inclusion of context-driven factors is a consequence of this kind of analysis.  For example, an ethanol plant in Nebraska draws its power from a comparatively coal-heavy electric grid than a similar plant in California - and the Nebraska plant must truck its produced fuel over the Rocky Mountains, a further source of pollution.  All else equal, an LCA standard produces an absolute preference for California-produced ethanol over Nebraska's. This was the basis for the lawsuit against the LCFS, which held that this was impermissible discrimination.  That lawsuit did not succeed.
I am interested in other examples of LCA being used as a regulatory tool or otherwise explicitly part of statutory language, inclusive of proposed legislation or regulations.  My interest is focused in the United States, but international examples are welcome as well.
